# Swap 2 div's order in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have 2 divs.

In HD screen I am having:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

But I need in mobile devices using media queries-

```
<div>2</div>
 <div>1</div>
```

I am just trying to change the order of divs in mobile screens.
Any fiddle will be highly helpful

Can anyone help me to get this done? Highly Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout, you can use the `order` CSS attribute inside a media query. But this requires you to wrap your two divs into a container that has `display: flex`. Read the linked guide for more info on flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You must use parent element as a flex and try to start from mobile device:

> display:flex

```css
  @media(min-width: 768px){
    .parent{display:flex;}
    .parent .a{order: 2}
    .parent .b{order: 1}
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">2</div>
  <div class="b">1</div>
</div>
```

It's an answer to the question but don't stop there. Try to learn and fix my example with separate file etc.
Use "flex-wrap: wrap;" to be sure that container stack

Comment: no need to set the order: just use flex-direction : column-reverse

Comment: @fcalderan yeah. True story. I just have one of many solutions.

Comment: @fcalderan This only applies when you indeed do this for just 2 divs. When you have to reorder multiple divs, you might want to use `order`.

Comment: am not getting the same in codepen
i need like this in mobile .  2                              
                                          1
that is 1 below 2 ,not just on same row. @Pa

Comment: Open codepen in full page :) no style to not disrupt